# Timespan calculate difference

Tags: c#

I got 2 textboxes, and want to calculate the difference of the time between those 2.
And i got it working, but it´s barely, at least i think i just made it working with some "hacks".

It will also fail if something is not correct, and will throw an exception, which i would like to prevent (probably with an IF, to just ignore if it´s not correct).

Here is the code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var first = TimeSpan.ParseExact(First.Text.Replace("-", ":").Remove(First.Text.LastIndexOf("-"), 1).Insert(First.Text.Length - 4, "."), "g", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var last = TimeSpan.ParseExact(Last.Text.Replace("-", ":").Remove(First.Text.LastIndexOf("-"), 1).Insert(First.Text.Length - 4, "."), "g", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var difference = first - last;
            CalcDiff.Text = difference.TotalSeconds.ToString("F3");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

AS you can see, it´s many "replace" and all kinds of stuff, just to make it work.

The formatting i am providing is this:

2013-05-22 12-07-55-324

And for that matter, i only care about the time, which is: 12-07-55-324

So, i am telling it to replace - with :, to just make itwork, and stuff like that.

So, is there a way to improve that. And can i make some kind of Condition, so i can´t just, press the button, and it will fail if it´s not correct (for example the formatting is wrong, or it´s nothing there, or Text instead).

Comment: Since you're using a non-standard format, have you tried implementing a custom `IFormatProvider` and using that as your second argument for `Parse` (or one of its variations)?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, link is appreciated:)

Comment: This is where a simple search will find an answer ;) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx

Comment: @Tawnos that looks to hard for me, think i will go with the manual way "xxxx-xx..." to tell the format. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `TimeOfDay` of a `DateTime` which can be parsed via [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
string dtString = "2013-05-22 12-07-55-324";
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.ParseExact(dtString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/aJIz8M)</kbd>

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to check if the string can be parsed successfully:

```
DateTime firstDt;
DateTime lastDt;
if ( DateTime.TryParseExact(First.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out firstDt )
  && DateTime.TryParseExact(Last.Text,  "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out lastDt ))
{
    // successfully parsed both Datetimes
    var difference = firstDt.TimeOfDay - lastDt.TimeOfDay;
    CalcDiff.Text = difference.TotalSeconds.ToString("F3");
}
```

Here is a more readable approach since you are concerned about complexity of the `if`-statement:

```
DateTime firstDt, lastDt;
bool canParseFirst = DateTime.TryParseExact(First.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out firstDt);
bool canParseLast =  DateTime.TryParseExact(Last.Text,  "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out lastDt );
if(canParseFirst && canParseLast)
{
    // successfully parsed both Datetimes
    var difference = firstDt.TimeOfDay - lastDt.TimeOfDay;
    CalcDiff.Text = difference.TotalSeconds.ToString("F3");
}
else
{ 
    // inform the user
}
```

Comment: But how can i them calculate the difference, as ts is only alive within the IF.

Comment: Oh, didn´t see that, just looked at the Timespan ts. But so, i should have 2 of those if? But how can i containt the "difference" calculate within that? meaning, if both wasn´t parsed correctly, Don´t calculate.

Comment: @user2587718: I have edited my answer to show a complete example. Note that i have presumed that you are using 24h clock, otherwise you have to use lowercase hours ,so `hh` instead of `HH`.

Comment: Ah so you needed to do a long if, but this works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @user2587718: You can also use `TryParseExact` to initialize a `bool` variable (e.g. `canParseFirst` + `canParseLast`). That might increase readability: `if(canParseFirst && canParseLast) ...`.

Comment: That´s true, but it looks okay when you did a row space. But i wonder, is it possible to make it work with more, for example, if i only write, 12-07-55-324, it will get (oh, it´s xx-xx-xx-xxx, xxx must be fff, and th rest are behind it)  if you get waht i mean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36492/discussion-between-user2587718-and-tim-schmelter)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) instead, you'll still be able to get the difference in the two times pretty easily (just Google finding the difference between two `DateTime` objects), plus you can use [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) to specify strange formats like you have there. PLUS that method will help alleviate those pesky exceptions you mentioned! Instead of throwing an exception, it will simply return `true` if it parsed successfully and false otherwise.

Comment: But don´t i need to have a super long If then, which contains both the TryParse? if(tryparse........ && tryparse.....) ?